# Usage of gethostbyaddr under a docker container return the ip itself instead of the hostname

Tags: php, docker, wsl-2

The php function `gethostbyaddr` stop working under my docker container. I'm trying to figure why but I find no lead.

Example:

```php
<?php
echo gethostbyaddr("66.249.66.1");
```

The expected result should be:
`crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com.`
But I got `66.249.66.1`.

When I try `host 66.249.66.1` into my WSL, it works:

> 1.66.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com.

But when I try it inside my Docker container, I got:

> 1.66.249.66.in-addr.arpa has no PTR record

Does someone faced the same issue?